# SuppressWarnings("deprecation") for one line in java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, suppress-warnings

I am working with threads and using thread.stop(); to end a thread for a temporary solution to a problem I was having. I understand that it is deprecated and should not be used, but how do I suppress the compiler warning for that one line only? I want to continue getting deprecated warnings for the rest of my class, just not that one line. I tried using the code below and got the error "Annotations are not allowed here" on the @SupressWarnings("deprecation") line. What is the correct way to suppress this error?

```java
class Handeler {
   private Thread thread;
   .....
   void stopThread() {
      if(thread!=null && thread.isAlive()) {                 
         @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            thread.stop();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can annotate the method instead:

```
class Handeler {
   private Thread thread;
   .....
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   void stopThread() {
      if(thread!=null && thread.isAlive()) {                 
            thread.stop();
      }
   }
}
```

This annotation on a single line is not allowed.

Answer (score 4):

You could suppress warning using comment:

```
void stopThread() {
      if(thread!=null && thread.isAlive()) {

          //noinspection deprecation
          thread.stop();
      }
}
```

Comment: This seems IDE-specific. Does it stop warnings being emitted by the compiler (javac and ecj)?

Comment: This didn't work with me on Android Studio Electric Eel (IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1)